# Creating apklibs with maven and IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, maven

I'm creating a apklib from sliding menu because I couldn't find any maven repository. The problem is that when I try from intellij, It imports the library but doesn't add the dependencies to sliding menu library and I have to add it manually.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.slidingmenu</groupId>
<artifactId>library</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
<type>apklib</type>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.maps</groupId>
        <artifactId>maps</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v13</artifactId>
            <version>r12</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.rtyley</groupId>
            <artifactId>roboguice-sherlock</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.roboguice</groupId>
            <artifactId>roboguice</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <nativeLibrariesDirectory>ignored</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I create the zip, according to the instructions on maven plugin and then I push it to ~/.m2 with this command:

```
 mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file -DgroupId=com.slidingmenu -DartifactId=library -Dfile=sliding-menu.apklib -Dversion=1.2 -Dpackaging=apklib
```

Comment: did you find any solution? I'm just at the same point which you were once. I'll be very happy if you share with me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `com.slidingmenu` in your local repository with `mvn clean install` instead of `install:install-file`

`mvn clean install` will put all the meta-data and the dependencies required by maven in your local repository (i.e. `~/.m2/repository`).

In your apk, specify the artifact `com.slidingmenu` as a dependency of type `apklib`

I hope it will solve your problems.

Comment: OP is referring to an external project that doesn't support building using Maven.  The usual technique afaik for these type of libraries is to zip them with a .apklib extension, and then deploy to your local repo using the install-file goal.  The problem is intellij doesn't seem to like this...

Comment: As far as I understand the OP is referring to an external project not available in a public maven-repo. But it seems to support building with maven since the OP posted the pom.xml. And the problem is not Intellij not liking it, but the fact that when you run install-file without specifying a proper pom.xml: maven create one very simple pom.xml for you, but it doesn't contains real dependencies.